# Let g(x) be a non negative continuous function on R such that $g(x) +g(x+\frac{1}{3})=5$..

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

Let g(x) be a non negative continuous function on R such that $g(x) +g(x+\frac{1}{3})=5$ then calculate the value of integral $\int^{1200}_0 g(x) dx$

My approach :

$g(x) +g(x+\frac{1}{3})=5$.....(1)
put x = x +$\frac{1}{3}$

we get $g(x+\frac{1}{3})+g(x+\frac{2}{3})=5$...(2)

Subtracting (2) from (1) we get

$g(x) = g(x+\frac{2}{3})$

$\Rightarrow $ g(x) is periodic with period $\frac{2}{3}$

So we can write the integral as

$1800 \int^{2/3}_0 g(x)dx $

now what to do further please suggest , will be of great help. thanks

Comment: Hint: Separate the last integral into two parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**THIS IS COMPLETE SOLUTION.... LOOK ONLY AT LINE 1 FOR HINT**

After this , we observe that,

$$\int_0^{2/3}g(x)dx   = \int_0^{2/3}g(x+1/3)dx = I $$

Since $g(x)$ is periodic.
Hence, we get that

$$\int_0^{2/3}g(x) + g(x+1/3)dx = 2I = \int_0^{2/3}5dx = 10/3$$

Hence , we get $I = 5/3$

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach is to note that

$$\begin{align*}
6000&=\int_0^{1200}5\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{1200}\left(g(x)+g\left(x+\frac13\right)\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^{1200}g(x)\,dx+\int_{\frac13}^{1200+\frac13}g(x)\,dx\\
&=2\int_0^{1200}g(x)\,dx+\int_{1200}^{1200+\frac13}g(x)\,dx-\int_0^{\frac13}g(x)\,dx
\end{align*}$$

and then use what you know about the periodic nature of $g$ to deal with the last two terms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this solution is the fastest but I am pretty sure it is the most accurate one.

Step 1: multiply the differential infinitesimal (dx) on $g(x) +g(x+\frac{1}{3})=5$

$(g(x) +g(x+\frac{1}{3}))dx= 5dx$

Because of the multiplication's disturbution law:

$g(x)dx +g(x+\frac{1}{3})dx= 5dx$

Step 2: integral two side with from low limit(0) to upper limmit(1/3):

$\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}}g(x)dx + g(x+\frac{1}{3})dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} 5 dx$

By the integration's indentitiy:

$\int_0^{\frac{1}{3}}g(x)dx + \int_0^{\frac{1}{3}}g(x+1/3)dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} 5 dx$

substitude x for x+1/3

$\int^{2/3}_0 g(x)dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{3}}g(x)dx + \int_\frac{1}{3}^{\frac{2}{3}}g(x)dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{3}} 5 dx = \frac{5}{3}$